# How to clear the paint?

Tags: android, paint

I am trying to erase the paint in my app? but it is not erase, when i am moving from one activity to another activity i want to erase the paint.
please help me... 
This is the code i am using

```
 public class MyView extends View {
            //int bh = originalBitmap.getHeight();
            //int bw = originalBitmap.getWidth(); 

            public MyView (Context c,int w,int h)  {  
                super(c);
                mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w,h,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                //Bitmap mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap,200,200,true);
                mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
                mPath = new Path();
                mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
                mBitmapPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC)) ;                 
            }
            @Override
            protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
                super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);           
                /*mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bw, bh, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);*/
            } 




            @Override 
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {   
                canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
                canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
            }
            ////////************touching evants for painting**************///////
            private float mX, mY;
            private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 5;
            private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
                mPath.reset();
                mPath.moveTo(x, y);
                mX = x;
                mY = y;
            }
            private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
                float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
                float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
                if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
                    mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
                    mX = x;
                    mY = y;
                }
            }

            private void touch_up() {
                mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
                // commit the path to our offscreen
                mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
                // kill this so we don't double draw
                mPath.reset();
            }
```

Comment: you have any idea erase the paint.........

Comment: view.invalidate is what is used to reset the custom view

Comment: iam use invalidate drawing the paint not possible

Comment: @Swarna: no iam using different canvas for both activities

Comment: @Swarna my problem is solved view.invalidate()..thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i am use ing this my problem is solved

```
    mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPath.reset(); 
    mView.invalidate();
```

Comment: How ur using this methods can u please post some code here.. it would be helpful for me.. thanks in advance

Comment: @andriod_testing use this in button click activity. change one activity to another activity path is erase...

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy Can u solve this issue, I search everywhere but not got the perfect answer for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229496/eraser-with-porterduff-mode-clear-always-draws-a-transparent-line

Comment: see here may be it is usefull http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2012/10/free-hand-graw.html and here http://polamreddyn.blogspot.in/2013/02/paint-undo-and-redo-example.html

Answer (score 1):

Use invalidate it will help you to redraw in the canvas.

Comment: drawing is ok iam paint in first activity click the button go to next activity, when ever  write the paint in first activity that paint show in second activity i want erase in that first activity paint, in the second activity.

Comment: are you using the same canvas for both the activities?